# Why is constructor not being recognized when being referenced?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I'm trying to code a token and it is not recognizing constructor.. why? [image]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to deploy the `ERC20` (parent) contract, not the `Avenger`.

Select the `Avenger` contract in the "Deploy & Run transactions" tab, under the "Contract" label (just above the orange "Deploy" button). Then it will ask you to pass the constructor param(s).